# google sheets creating a button that on clicking it, it will give the next cell down from a list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i want to create a function that displays in cell D2 a cell from the list A2:A8 and when i click on a button "down" it will display in D2 the next cell down from the list A2:a8. and when i click on a button  "up" it will display in D2 the next cell up in the list A2:a8. and when i click the button "reset" it will display in D2 the cell A2.
greatly appreciated! Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Probably not with a button, but check Tools -> Macros

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You have 3 buttons on a sheet in Google Spreadsheet.
- When you click the button, you want to change the value of cell "D2".
- For example, when there is a list that the cells "A2:A8" have `a,b,c,d,e,f,g`,

  - When you click the up button, you want to up one element in the list the values from `g` to `a`.
  - When you click the down button, you want to down one element in the list the values from `a` to `g`.
  - When you click the reset button, you want to set the top element in the list. For the sample values, `a` is set.

In this case, I think that it is required to use Google Apps Script because the script is run by clicking the button. In this answer, I would like to propose the following sample script.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of the Google Spreadsheet. And please assign the function names of `up`, `down` and `reset` to the buttons of `up`, `down` and `reset`, respectively. By this, each function is run by clicking the button.

```
function handler_(button) {
  var lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();
  if (lock.tryLock(10000)) {
    try {
      const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      const range = sheet.getRange("D2");
      let cellD2 = range.getValue();
      const list = sheet.getRange("A2:A8").getValues().flat();
      if (cellD2 == "") cellD2 = list[0];
      const index = list.indexOf(cellD2);
      const newIndex = button == "up" ? index - 1 : button == "down" ? index + 1 : 0;
      if (newIndex >= 0 && newIndex < list.length) {
        range.setValue(list[newIndex]);
      }
    } catch(e) {
      throw new Error(e);
    } finally {
      lock.releaseLock();
    }
  }
}

const up = _ => handler_("up");
const down = _ => handler_("down");
const reset = _ => handler_("reset");
```

#### Result:

When above script is used for your sample Spreadsheet, it becomes as follows.

[image]

#### Note:

- This is a simple sample script. So please modify it to your actual situation.

#### References:

- [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock)

Comment: Hi Dobromir Velev thanks a lot it works on my computer perfectly wow yet i wanted it to work on my mobile phone and when i click the button it select the button and nothing Happened.
do you know how to make work?
your help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: @Tanaike Actually, the OP ended up asking a new "question", including the list in your answer; without any question... https://stackoverflow.com/q/66004729/8376184 I don't think that's what you meant...

Comment: @FZs Thank you for your support. I would like to check it. When I could find the solution or workaround, I would like to answer it. By the way, I thought that OP might misunderstand my name.