# Google Sheets: Making a button to show next in list of range including cell format

Tags: google-sheets

so let me start this off by saying I don't code so this is probably something super easy.
I am trying to get a button that changes the data and cell color of a line based on what is in a range.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65697075/google-sheets-creating-a-button-that-on-clicking-it-it-will-give-the-next-cell) before which has an example code that I modified to do the entire line (theres is probably a much easier way to do it then how i did it.) but i also need the color of the cells to be transfered, how would I do this?

[sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLdoz.png)

```
function handler_(button) {
  var lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();
  if (lock.tryLock(10000)) {
    try {
      const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      const range = sheet.getRange("A2");
      let A2 = range.getValue();
      const list = sheet.getRange("A8:A35").getValues().flat();
      if (A2 == "") A2 = list[0];
      const index = list.indexOf(A2);
      const newIndex = button == "up" ? index - 1 : button == "down" ? index + 1 : 0;
      if (newIndex >= 0 && newIndex < list.length) {
        range.setValue(list[newIndex]);
      }
    } catch(e) {
      throw new Error(e);
    } finally {
      lock.releaseLock();
    }
    try {
      const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      const range = sheet.getRange("B2");
      let B2 = range.getValue();
      const list = sheet.getRange("B8:B35").getValues().flat();
      if (B2 == "") B2 = list[0];
      const index = list.indexOf(B2);
      const newIndex = button == "up" ? index - 1 : button == "down" ? index + 1 : 0;
      if (newIndex >= 0 && newIndex < list.length) {
        range.setValue(list[newIndex]);
      }
    } catch(e) {
      throw new Error(e);
    } finally {
      lock.releaseLock();
    }
    try {
      const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      const range = sheet.getRange("C2");
      let C2 = range.getValue();
      const list = sheet.getRange("C8:C35").getValues().flat();
      if (C2 == "") C2 = list[0];
      const index = list.indexOf(C2);
      const newIndex = button == "up" ? index - 1 : button == "down" ? index + 1 : 0;
      if (newIndex >= 0 && newIndex < list.length) {
        range.setValue(list[newIndex]);
      }
    } catch(e) {
      throw new Error(e);
    } finally {
      lock.releaseLock();
    }
        try {
      const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      const range = sheet.getRange("D2");
      let D2 = range.getValue();
      const list = sheet.getRange("D8:D35").getValues().flat();
      if (D2 == "") D2 = list[0];
      const index = list.indexOf(D2);
      const newIndex = button == "up" ? index - 1 : button == "down" ? index + 1 : 0;
      if (newIndex >= 0 && newIndex < list.length) {
        range.setValue(list[newIndex]);
      }
    } catch(e) {
      throw new Error(e);
    } finally {
      lock.releaseLock();
    }
        try {
      const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      const range = sheet.getRange("E2");
      let E2 = range.getValue();
      const list = sheet.getRange("E8:E35").getValues().flat();
      if (E2 == "") E2 = list[0];
      const index = list.indexOf(E2);
      const newIndex = button == "up" ? index - 1 : button == "down" ? index + 1 : 0;
      if (newIndex >= 0 && newIndex < list.length) {
        range.setValue(list[newIndex]);
      }
    } catch(e) {
      throw new Error(e);
    } finally {
      lock.releaseLock();
    }
        try {
      const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      const range = sheet.getRange("F2");
      let F2 = range.getValue();
      const list = sheet.getRange("F8:F35").getValues().flat();
      if (F2 == "") F2 = list[0];
      const index = list.indexOf(F2);
      const newIndex = button == "up" ? index - 1 : button == "down" ? index + 1 : 0;
      if (newIndex >= 0 && newIndex < list.length) {
        range.setValue(list[newIndex]);
      }
    } catch(e) {
      throw new Error(e);
    } finally {
      lock.releaseLock();
    }
  }
}

const up = _ => handler_("up");
const down = _ => handler_("down");
const reset = _ => handler_("reset");
```